# Assembly: division using the values in two 32-bit registers as if they were one 64-bit integer

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, integer-division, cpu-registers

I have a 64 bit integer I need to print in assembly, but I am working on a 32-bit machine, so I have my 64-bit integer stored in two 32-bit registers. The high part of the integer is stored in %edx and the low part is stored in %eax.

I know how to print a 32-bit integer no problem, just divide by 10 continuously and print the remainders.

I also know how to multiply my 64-bit number by a 32-bit.

But what is killing me is the division:

From what I have gathered, I think I have to divide each of my registers %edx and %eax by ten, and somehow combine the two answers, as I would with multiplication, but what do I do with the remainders and quotients of each division?

I am working with the GNU assembler using the AT&T x86 syntax on a 32-bit Linux machine.
Thanks

Comment: I suggest you use iterative subtraction, that should be easy enough to implement and you even get the digits in the correct order ;)

Comment: [DIV](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/DIV.html) already divides edx:eax by the source operand, doing 64b / 32b => 32b division.  The issue is that it faults with a divide error (same as division by zero) if the quotient doesn't fit in eax.  On Linux this triggers a SIGFPE.  If you only need rcgldr's answer if the quotient might require 64 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has shown up several times recently. The algorithm is similar to doing division with pencil and paper, dividing a dividend of multiple digits by a single digit divisor. Here's a code snippet, with the 64 bit dividend kept in edi:esi. Note this same method could be extended to divide a very large dividend stored in memory to be divided by a 32 bit divisor.

```
        .data
decstr  db      24 dup (0)
pfstr   db      '%','s',0dh,0ah,0
        .code
        extrn   _printf:NEAR
_main   proc    near
        mov     edi,000000002h          ;edi = high order dvnd
        mov     esi,04CB016EAh          ;esi = low  order dvnd
        lea     ebx,decstr+23           ;ebx = ptr to end string
        mov     ecx,10                  ;ecx = 10 (constant)
div0:   xor     edx,edx                 ;clear edx
        mov     eax,edi                 ;divide high order
        div     ecx
        mov     edi,eax
        mov     eax,esi                 ;divide low order
        div     ecx
        mov     esi,eax
        add     dl,'0'                  ;store ascii digit
        dec     ebx
        mov     [ebx],dl
        mov     eax,edi                 ;repeat till dvnd == 0
        or      eax,esi
        jnz     div0
        push    ebx                     ;display string
        push    offset pfstr
        call    _printf
        add     sp,8
        xor     eax,eax
        ret
_main   endp
```

Comment: Note that once EDI <= 9, you can switch to a secondary "one division per digit" loop.